# Joining 3 foreign_keys in a rails has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, redmine

In my application, I have 3 tables: Responsability, Knowledge and level.

Need through an association table with the following fields:

```
-> Responsability_id 
-> Knowledge_id 
-> Level_id
```

And in a view that I created in the register of Responsability, saying that this position instance, has some knowledge and level for their knowledge.

Being that the knowledge will be shown in check-box's, and in front of a select for each
select the level.

Any idea how to make this association?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Level
  has_many :knowledges
  has_many :responsibilities, through: :knowledges
end

class Knowledge
  has_many :responsibilities
  belongs_to :level
end

class Responsibility
  belongs_to :knowledge
  delegate :level, to: :knowledge
end
```

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association